# What is the length of maximum text inside an xml node?

Tags: xml, xml-generation

I'm generating `XML` file using PHP, In my Generated XML File there is a `<text-content></text-content>` node with large amount of text. So My question is, Does `XML` have any limitation in number characters inside a single node ? If So, What is the length of maximum text inside an xml node ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no limit enforced by the specification.

The usual issues of memory and other system resources apply though.